# Symfony 2 generate:bundle - with or without namespace /Bundle/

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I'm new to Symfony. I went through the documentation and recent tutorials about Symfony 2. When creating a bundle, documentation always tells use to "Vendor/Bundle/BlogBundle" like path (including middle 'Bundle'folder). But when I'm reading most of the tutorials they have used 'Vendor/BlogBundle' like path (not include a 'Bundle' folder). So can anybody explain the purpose of using separate 'Bundle' folder to store bundles under the Vendor folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [How to use Best Practices for Structuring Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name) you can see, both methods are common. An extra `Bundle` in the namespace if mostly used for structuring if you have `Component`s, `Bridge`s or any other libraries under the same vendor name space. E.g. like [symfony framework itself](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony).